# Optimal number of mappers required in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am running a cross product operation and storing the results in a table. The number of rows in table1 and table2 is ~300K and ~15K respectively. The query is like

```
create table table3 
as 
select a.var1*b.var1+......+a.var_n.b.var_n as score 
from 
table1 a , table2b
```

I observed that the process is running fastest at 2000 to 3000 mappers as compared to much higher number of mappers allocated (5000).

My questions are :

1. Does increasing the number of mapper really speed up the process?
2. Is there any way to to figure out the optimal number of mapper for a process ?

Comment: do you mean dot product?

Comment: No . You can see that I am not using any condition for joining two tables .Its cross product joining . Thats why its taking so much time . I am trying to calculate similarity score for each of customers with respect to each item. Table1 is customer table table 2 is item's table